# is it halal to look at women in bikini without lust?

Tags: sex, zina

Asalam walaikum,

Is it halal to look at semi naked women without lust?

Most explanations I read prohibiting it  say so with lust rather than leaving it as haram.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter if it's lust or not, it's **haram**. If you're a male, you are told to lower your gaze.

> "Tell the believing men to reduce [some] of their vision and guard
> their private parts. That is purer for them. Indeed, Allah is
> Acquainted with what they do." 
>  -Qur'an 24:30

Even if you don't look at her with desire, Satan can still tempt and arouse you to. There is no guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

It is impermissible to look at the áwrah of a man or woman, regardless of if it is with lust or without, except in circumstances where there is genuine need.